# MVC2: SQL Server table --> Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

is there an easy way to export a SQL Server table into a xls spreadsheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a nice and easy solution

http://blog.wiredworx.co.uk/website-and-seo/c-tutorials-and-tips-visual-studio/exporting-to-an-excel-file-from-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to do this... not very MVCish anyway. There's no need to write directly to the response.

Answer (score 0):

[NPoi](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). You should create the spredsheet in memory and send it via the File action result.